# Efficiently calculate a metric on all pairwise combinations of array-elements

Tags: python, numpy, combinatorics

I have the following code where I calculate a mean difference of array elements, each with every other. Is there a way to do this more efficiently than in a nested loop, like in a numpy-function?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.02625, -0.04125, -0.00875, -0.05625, 0.04375, 0.03625])

delta = []
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
  for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
    delta.append(a[i] - a[j])    
delta = np.array(delta)

avg_dist = np.sum(np.abs(delta)) / delta.size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Get the pairwise indices with [`np.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)/[`np.tril_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html), use those to index into input array and thus compute differences -

```
I,J = np.triu_indices(len(a),1)
delta = a[I] - a[J]
```

**Approach #2**

We could also make use of `slicing` with one loop, which should be memory-efficient as it avoids generating the indices, as done in the previous approach -

```
def pairwise_diff(a):
    n = len(a)
    N = n*(n-1)//2
    idx = np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(n-1,0,-1).cumsum() ))
    start, stop = idx[:-1], idx[1:]
    out = np.empty(N,dtype=a.dtype)
    for j,i in enumerate(range(n-1)):
        out[start[j]:stop[j]] = a[i,None] - a[i+1:]
    return out
```

Timings on a large array with `10000` elements -

```
In [214]: a = np.random.rand(10000)

# Approach #1
In [215]: %%timeit
     ...: I,J = np.triu_indices(len(a),1)
     ...: delta = a[I] - a[J]
1 loop, best of 3: 627 ms per loop

# Approach #2
In [216]: %timeit pairwise_diff(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 69.1 ms per loop

# Original approach
In [217]: %%timeit
     ...: delta = []
     ...: for i in range(len(a) - 1):
     ...:   for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
     ...:     delta.append(a[i] - a[j])
1 loop, best of 3: 15.7 s per loop
```